# Is 802.1x port security enforces IP uniqueness

Tags: ip, ieee-802.1x

I know that 802.1x can track MAC addresses. If MAC address is used on one port then you can prohibit it from being used on another port.

Can 802.11x protocol do the same thing for IP addresses?

My underlying question which triggered that one. Can a user connect to 802.1x using his/her credentials and after change IP address to somebody else IP address to get access to some resources which are protected based on IP address?

Comment: dot1x only establishes the user's identity; it has nothing to with IP addressing

Comment: Consider implementing Layer2 security in parrallel with dot1x. Many providers integrate these features into their switching products. Look up port-security with dhcp-snooping and dynamic arp inspection from your preferred vendor. example:-   http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.3/topics/example/port-security-server-on-second-switch-same-vlan.html

Comment: @user4565 Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for (DHCP-snooping and DAI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dot1x only establishes the user's identity; it has nothing to with IP addressing